# Stop new object from updating with old object's variables

Tags: php, class, variables, object, clone

I'm trying to do something like:

```
$obj2 = $obj1
```

where $var1 is an object, the problem is that I want $obj2 to be like a snap shot of $obj1 - exactly how it is at that moment, but as $obj1's variables change, $obj2's change as well.  Is this even possible? Or am I going to have to create a new "dummy" class just so I can create a clone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply clone the object, like so:

```
$obj2 = clone $obj1;
```

Any modifications to the members of `$obj1` after the above statement will not be reflected in `$obj2`.

Comment: Awesome, I feel stupid now, lol.  Thanks, that worked out easier/better then I had ever hoped for!

Answer (score 1):

Objects are passed by reference in PHP.  This means that when you assign an object to new variable, that new variable contains a reference to the same object, NOT a new copy of the object.  This rule applies when assigning variables, passing variables into methods, and passing variables into functions.

In your case, both `$obj1` and `$obj2` reference the same object, so modifying either one will modify the same object.

Comment: @KingCrunch Thank you for the link.  I will be sure not to use the word "pointer" when talking about references in PHP.